# Getting AttributeError: im must have seek method while trying to save as GIF

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I am trying to save a bunch of images in a folder as a gif.

**My code is as follows:**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageSequence 
import imageio


im1 = Image.open('../input/imageslaptop/temp2.png')
images = []
for k in range(3,53):
    f="../input/imageslaptop/temp"+str(k)+".png"
    images.append(np.asarray(Image.open(f)))
images = np.array(images)
im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=images, duration=5100, loop=0)
```

```
print (version.parse(Image.PILLOW_VERSION) )
```

gives 8.0.1

[image: error]

Comment: Please copy the entire error message and include it as code (not as a link to a picture).

Comment: I don't know if that's helpful but here's the docs for [`PIL.Image.save`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save).

Comment: Does it work if you replace `"out.gif"` with `"out.png"`?

Comment: why do you use `np.array`? I suspect it will work when you remove `np.asarray()` from `images.append(np.asarray(Image.open(f)))` and remove line `images = np.array(images)`.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image.

Answer (score 3):

You get error because you convert Pillow images to `numpy` arrays

Code works correctly without `np.asarray` and `np.array`

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('../input/imageslaptop/temp2.png')

images = []

for k in range(3, 53):
    path = "../input/imageslaptop/temp" + str(k) + ".png"
    images.append(Image.open(path))

im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=images, duration=5100, loop=0)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to convert Pillow images to numpy arrays to make some changes then you have to convert arrays back to Pillow images before saving.

```
images = [Image.fromarray(img) for img in images]
```

---

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im1 = Image.open('../input/imageslaptop/temp2.png')

images = []

for k in range(3, 53):
    path = "../input/imageslaptop/temp" + str(k) + ".png"
    images.append(np.asarray(Image.open(path)))

# ... here make some change on images ... 

images = [Image.fromarray(img) for img in images]

im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=images, duration=5100, loop=0)
```